# Tweaking display of quality histogram, exporting the colormap

Tags: histogram, colorbar, colormap, meshlab

I have a couple of questions, which get tied back to a simple need - I want to use the quality histogram as a colorbar in my publication. To export it along with labels for publication, I tried just taking a snapshot with the appropriate tool, but if I use [alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W51ac.png)/ solid white background the text/ colorbars is not visible. If I use the solid [black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70G4Z.png) or meshlab background, the text is white, or can not be used directly in publication.

My questions are as follows:

- I know how to change the text color on meshlab window. Is there a similar function to change the text font size on meshlab window?
- As a more demanding question, is there a way I can import the quality map file into matlab or some other software, and plot a custom colorbar. I will append my .qmap file here, but it seems that the color field is empty, and I can not reproduce the colors without them.

%%%%%QMAP FILE TO FOLLOW%%%%%

```
// COLOR BAND FILE STRUCTURE - first row: RED CHANNEL DATA - second row GREEN CHANNEL DATA - third row: BLUE CHANNEL DATA
// CHANNEL DATA STRUCTURE - the channel structure is grouped in many triples. The items of each triple represent respectively: X VALUE, Y_LOWER VALUE, Y_UPPER VALUE of each node-key of the transfer function
0;0.5;0.125;1;0.375;1;0.625;0;0.875;0;1;0;
0;0;0.125;0;0.375;1;0.625;1;0.875;0;1;0;
0;0;0.125;0;0.375;0;0.625;1;0.875;1;1;0.5;
//THE FOLLOWING 4 VALUES REPRESENT EQUALIZER SETTINGS - the first and the third values represent respectively the minimum and the maximum quality values used in histogram, the second one represent the position (in percentage) of the middle quality, and the last one represent the level of brightness as a floating point number (0 copletely dark, 1 original brightness, 2 completely white)
-0.001;0.714286;0.0004;1;
```